# Steam64 ID Changes When Displayed on Website, But API Response Appears Correct

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am facing an issue where the Steam64 ID, retrieved from a Flask API, seems correct when logged on the server side, but when I display it on my React website, it appears to be different
when i display on my website : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLIbt.png)

I have a Flask API that receives a Steam64 ID through a POST request, performs some transformations, and sends back the processed data to my React front-end:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIrcb.png)

I verified the server-side logs: Checked the Flask server logs to ensure that the Steam64 ID is received correctly and matches the expected value (76561198869191933).

Inspected React component code: Reviewed the relevant part of my React component where the Steam64 ID is displayed (userData.Steam64_ID). Confirmed that the property is correctly accessed.

I expected the Steam64 ID to be consistently displayed on the website as 76561198869191933, matching the value logged on the server side.Despite the correct value being logged on the server side, the displayed Steam64 ID on the website appears as 76561198869191940.

this is my frontend :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import '../styles/SteamLookup.css';

function SteamLookup() {
  const [steamId, setSteamId] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSteamIdChange = (e) => {
    setSteamId(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/getSteamUser', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ steamId }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('API Response:', data); 
        setUserData(data);
        setError(null);
      } else {
        setError(data.error || 'Unknown error');
        setUserData(null);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
      setError('Error fetching user data. Please try again.');
      setUserData(null);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="steam-lookup-contain">
      <h2 className="steam-lookup-title">Enter Steam ID</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="steam-lookup-input"
          type="text"
          value={steamId}
          onChange={handleSteamIdChange}
          placeholder="76561197960287930"
        />
        <button className="steam-lookup-submit-btn" type="submit" disabled={loading}>
          {loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Submit'}
        </button>
      </form>

      {userData && (
        <div className="steam-lookup-results">
          <h3 className="steam-lookup-res-title">Steam User Data</h3>
          <div className="steam-lookup-flex-box">
          <p><img className="Steam-Avatar"src={userData.ProfileImage} alt="Steam Avatar" /></p>
            <div className="steam-lookup-details">
              <p> Username: <span className="steam-lookup-user-details">{userData.Username}</span></p>
              <p>Account ID: <span className="steam-lookup-user-details">{userData.Account_ID}</span></p>
              <p>Steam64 ID: <span className="steam-lookup-user-details">{userData.Steam64_ID}</span></p>
              <p>Steam2 ID: <span className="steam-lookup-user-details">{userData.Steam2_ID}</span></p>
              <p>Steam3 ID: <span className="steam-lookup-user-details">{userData.Steam3_ID}</span></p>
              <p>FiveM HEX: <span className="steam-lookup-user-details">{userData.FiveM_Hex_id}</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      {error && (
        <div className="steam-lookup-error-message">
          <p>{error}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SteamLookup;
```

this is my flask code :

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import requests

session = requests.Session()

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  

api_key = 'steam api key here'  




 #"few more functions for calculating each value....."



def get_steam_user_details(steam64_id):
        url = f'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key={api_key}&steamids={steam64_id}'
        response = session.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json().get('response', {}).get('players', [{}])[0]
    
    @app.route('/api/getSteamUser', methods=['POST'])
    def get_steam_user():
        try:
            data = request.get_json()
            user_input = data.get('steamId')
            app.logger.info(f"Received request with steamId: {user_input}")
    
            FiveM_Hex_id, steam64_id, steam2_id, steam_3id, account_id = input_to_values(user_input)
    
            result = {
                "Account_ID": account_id,
                "FiveM_Hex_id": FiveM_Hex_id,
                "Steam64_ID": steam64_id,
                "Steam2_ID": steam2_id,
                "Steam3_ID": steam_3id,
                "FiveM_Hex_id": FiveM_Hex_id
    
            }
    
            
            user_details = get_steam_user_details(steam64_id)
            result.update({
                "ProfileImage": user_details.get('avatarfull', ''),
                "Username": user_details.get('personaname', '')
            })
            app.logger.info(
        f"Result:\n"
        f"FiveM_Hex_id: {result['FiveM_Hex_id']}\n"
        f"Steam64_ID: {result['Steam64_ID']}\n"
        f"Steam2_ID: {result['Steam2_ID']}\n"
        f"Steam3_ID: {result['Steam3_ID']}\n"
        f"Account_ID: {result['Account_ID']}\n"
        f"ProfileImage: {result['ProfileImage']}\n"
        f"Username: {result['Username']}"
    )
            response_text = (
                f"FiveM_Hex_id: {FiveM_Hex_id}\n"
                f"Steam64_ID: {steam64_id}\n"
                f"Steam2_ID: {steam2_id}\n"
                f"Steam3_ID: {steam_3id}\n"
                f"Account_ID: {account_id}"
            )
    
    
    
            return jsonify(result), 200
    
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.